# Repel / shadow text on ggplot2 likert() bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, likert

I'm experimenting with labels on likert() plot bars. Having fiddled with possible tools like ggrepel() and with_shadow() from ggfx(), I can't seem to identify the specific name of the element that I want to act on. I'm aware that geom_text_repel() will require me to specify aes() elements, but as these are all done implicitly by likert() I can't seem to identify the names of x and y in this case. Is it possible to modify labels on bars like I've got here?

Ideally, I'd like to repel and add drop-shadow/outline to the summary figures on each bar with a figure like this:

[image]

Here's a reproducible code sample:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(likert)
require(ggrepel)
library(hrbrthemes)

q41_data <- structure(list(`Cycle, walk or use public transport instead of using your car` = structure(c(5, 
3, 4, 5, 5, 3), label = "Household_Sustainability - Cycle, walk or use public transport instead of using your car", format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(Never = 1, 
Rarely = 2, Sometimes = 3, Often = 4, `Almost Always` = 5), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double")), `Have meat-free meals` = structure(c(4, 
5, 4, 5, 4, 3), label = "Household_Sustainability - Have meat-free meals", format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(Never = 1, 
Rarely = 2, Sometimes = 3, Often = 4, `Almost Always` = 5), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double")), `Try to influence family and friends to act in a pro-environmental way` = structure(c(5, 
NA, 4, 4, 5, 4), label = "Household_Sustainability - Try to influence family and friends to act in a pro-environmental way", format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(Never = 1, 
Rarely = 2, Sometimes = 3, Often = 4, `Almost Always` = 5), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double")), `Shop in second-hand or ‘antique’ shops instead of buying new things` = structure(c(NA, 
4, 4, 4, 5, 4), label = "Household_Sustainability - Shop in second-hand or ‘antique’ shops instead of buying new things", format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(Never = 1, 
Rarely = 2, Sometimes = 3, Often = 4, `Almost Always` = 5), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double")), `Choose not to fly` = structure(c(NA, 
2, 4, 4, 5, 3), label = "Household_Sustainability - Choose not to fly", format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(Never = 1, 
Rarely = 2, Sometimes = 3, Often = 4, `Almost Always` = 5), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double")), `Save energy at home` = structure(c(5, 
2, 4, 4, 5, 5), label = "Household_Sustainability - Save energy at home (e.g., by turning down the heating/thermostat)", format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(Never = 1, 
Rarely = 2, Sometimes = 3, Often = 4, `Almost Always` = 5), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double")), `Try to avoid food-waste at home` = structure(c(5, 
5, 4, 5, 5, 4), label = "Household_Sustainability - Try to avoid food-waste at home", format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(Never = 1, 
Rarely = 2, Sometimes = 3, Often = 4, `Almost Always` = 5), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double")), `Discuss climate change with family and friends` = structure(c(NA, 
3, 4, 5, 4, 3), label = "Household_Sustainability - Discuss climate change with family and friends", format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(Never = 1, 
Rarely = 2, Sometimes = 3, Often = 4, `Almost Always` = 5), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

title <- "How often do you do the following?"
caption <- "caption" 
q41_levels <- c("Never", "Rarely", "Sometimes", "Often", "Almost Always")
names(q41_data) <- c("Cycle, walk or use public transport instead of using your car", "Have meat-free meals", "Try to influence family and friends to act in a pro-environmental way", "Shop in second-hand or ‘antique’ shops instead of buying new things", "Choose not to fly", "Save energy at home", "Try to avoid food-waste at home", "Discuss climate change with family and friends")

q41_likert_table <- q41_data %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),
                factor, ordered = TRUE, levels = 1:5, labels=q41_levels)) %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  likert

plot(q41_likert_table, wrap=25, text.size=3, ordered=TRUE, low.color='#B18839', high.color='#590048', plot.percents=TRUE, plot.percent.low=FALSE, 
     plot.percent.high=FALSE, plot.percent.neutral=FALSE, text.color="white") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=c("100%","50%","0%","50%","100%"),limits=c(-70,90)) +
  labs(title = title, caption = NULL, y="") + guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL)) + 
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight = 0.9, size =12, hjust = 0))
# save to png file for reports
ggsave("figures/figure11.png", width = 22, height = 20, units = "cm")
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Quinten - I've added in a reproducible sample